# Ошибка "CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError: Cannot determine GraphQL input type for ..."

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql

Есть Mutation в Resolver:

```
@InputType()
class TurnInput {
  @Field(() => [Letter])
  word: [Letter]; // также пробовал Letter[] и просто [{}]

  @Field(() => Int)
  gameId: number

  @Field(() => Boolean)
  confirmed: boolean
}

@Mutation(() => Game)
async makeTurn(
  @Arg("input") input: TurnInput,
  @Ctx() { req }: MyContext
) { ... }
```

При запуске выводит ошибку:

> CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError: Cannot determine GraphQL input type for 'word' of 'TurnInput' class. Is the value, that is used as its TS type or explicit type, decorated with a proper decorator or is it a proper input value?

Есть ли какой-то способ передать в аргумент массив объектов своего типа? То есть там будет следующее примерно:

```
word: [
  {id: 1, char: 's'},
  {id: 2, char:'a'},
  {id: 3, char: 'n'},
  {id: 4, char: 'd'}
]
```

Comment: возможно, https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/issues/371#issuecomment-539183474 и следующий комментарий

Comment: @nörbörnën выручаете снова, благодарю. В самом деле нужно было InputType создавать отдельно. Напишите как ответ, пожалуйста, отмечу верным.

Comment: я в type-graphql вообще не разбираюсь, просто читать умею. сами напишите качественный ответ (и примите его), на so это - единственно правильный путь в такой ситуации. и в заголовок вынесите значимую часть сообщения, "CannotDetermineGraphQLTypeError: Cannot determine GraphQL input type for"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, в type-graphql в декораторе `@Arg()` можно использовать либо базовые типы, либо те, которые являются `@InputType`. В моём случае пришлось создавать отдельный `@InputType`, в котором содержатся необходимые поля:

```
@InputType()
export class CellInput implements Partial<Letter> {
  @Field(() => Int)
  boxNumber: number;

  @Field(() => String)
  char: string;

  @Field(() => Boolean)
  filled: boolean;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  isNew: boolean;
}
```

Comment: пометьте галкой «принятым», нормально же получилось

Comment: @nörbörnën через два дня только могу